# How to set column width in datatable

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, width

I have a table and I want to resize the column of the table

```
$("#tableSortable").dataTable({
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "aoColumns": [
        { sWidth: '1%' },
        { sWidth: '1%' },
        { sWidth: '1%' },
        { sWidth: '1%' } ]
    });
    tableSortable.fnDraw();
});
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: The combined cells of a table should add up to 100% width, therefore setting all to 1% is never going to have an effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in comments  Rory McCrossan mentioned . Yes the combined cells of table should  be 100%

Well in your case there are 4 columns right then its pretty straight farword .

```
"aoColumns": [
        { sWidth: '25%' },
        { sWidth: '25%' },
        { sWidth: '25%' },
        { sWidth: '25%' } ]
```

And if you want to do it in a different way you can set bAutoWidth:True .

Regards